# delegate is lost when self is equal to NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, facebook-sdk-4.0, nsobject

I'm using `[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];`for share a `photo` in facebook and self is equal to `NSObject` called SocialUtils.

I'm going directly to the library and putting logs.

```
NSLog(@"2");
NSLog(@"_sharePhotoContent _delegate intern is!!! %@",_delegate);
FBSDKGraphRequestHandler completionHandler = ^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) { //Passing this line the delegate is lost.
NSLog(@"3");
NSLog(@"_sharePhotoContent _delegate intern is!!! %@",_delegate);
```

This print is:

```
2
_sharePhotoContent _delegate intern is!!! <SocialUtils: 0x7f87f5707580>

3
_sharePhotoContent _delegate intern is!!! (null)
```

I tried the same, but this time self is equal to a `UIViewController` and works perfect, the delegate remains.

I do not understand why this happens, I need to have my separate controller logic because otherwise would mean to duplicate code in many UIViewControllers.

Someone can enlighten me because this happens?

Comment: are you maybe losing reference to `_sharePhotoContent` ?

Comment: @random I do not think so. Rarely when self be a viewcontroller does not happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delegate` property in FBSDKShareAPI is defined as weak. See here:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKSharing.h

It is possible your SocialUtils object is getting garbage collected. Does any other object have a strong reference to SocialUtils? If not, you could do something like this:

On YourAppDelegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SocialUtils *socialUtils;
```

Wherever you define SocialUtils:

```
SocialUtils *socialUtils = [[SocialUtils alloc] init];

YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.socialUtils = socialUtils;

[socialUtils shareToFacebook:...]
// this method ^ would call [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

It doesn't have to be on AppDelegate. It could also be on your ViewController as long as that doesn't get garbage collected during this time...

Comment: hi @Mark Watson works perfect in my xcode `7.2.1` but i test this same in a xcode `6.3.1` and not work, this crash -> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setSocialUtils:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff53b422ec0'` in line `appDelegate.socialUtils = socialUtils;` you have idea ? i need run in this xcode.

Comment: Sounds like either an issue with how you set up the property on AppDelegate, or how you are calling it. What does the property look like? Did you @synthesize it? (Not sure if required).

Comment: not man,I have not used @synthesize and use exactly `@property (nonatomic, strong) SocialUtils *socialUtils;` only